# Refresh Angular-ui bootstrap $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

So I have let's say:

```
$scope.errorMessage = "error1";
$scope.addCardModal = $modal.open({ 
    animation: true, 
    templateUrl: 'pages/templates/modals/modal.html',
    size: "lg",
    scope: $scope
});

$scope.checkError = function() {
    $scope.errorMessage = "another error";
}
```

And in my modal.html template I have:

```
<div ng-click="checkError()">Check Error</div>
<div ng-show="errorMessage">{{ errorMessage }}</div>
<div ng-click="errorMessage = false">Close</div>
```

- When I load my modal, the error messages shows like it is supposed to.
- When I click *Close*, the error message hides like it's supposed to.
- However, when I click *Check Error*, the `$scope` changes, but does not translate back to the modal.

Does anyone know why this may be happening and how I can get the `$scope` back into the modal? Because if I close the modal, and open it back up, the correct error message shows again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
$scope.errorMessage = "error1";
$scope.addCardModal = $modal.open({ 
    animation: true, 
    templateUrl: 'pages/templates/modals/modal.html',
    size: "lg",
    scope: $scope
});

$scope.checkError = function() {
    $scope.errorMessage = "another error";
}

$scope.toggleError = function(){
    $scope.errorMessage = "";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-click="checkError()">Check Error</div>
<div ng-show="errorMessage">{{ errorMessage }}</div>
<div ng-click="toggleError()">Close</div>
```

I added a toggleError() function, so that you empty your errorMessage string.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following:

```
$scope.checkError = function() {
  $scope.errorMessage = "another error";
  $scope.$apply();
}
```

Perhaps the $digest is not triggered.

EDIT:
The issue is not about $digest, but it is about different scopes being modified.
When the modal is created, a child $scope is assigned to it by Angular, so when this button is clicked:

```
<div ng-click="errorMessage = false">Close</div>
```

a new 'errorMessage' variable is created in the scope of the modal. Hence even if there are updates on the errorMessage variable in the parent scope, the modal will give priority to the errorMessage in its scope.

Comment: Just worked out why, solid_luffy is correct and the reason it works is because it calls toggleError which modifies the value in the right scope,
Instead what you were doing was creating the variable in the modal scope and not modifying the variable in the right scope (controller scope)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! That makes total sense

Comment: No problems, I edited the answer with that observation